# Store BLOB data with django and sqlite

Tags: python, django, orm, blob, blobstorage

First of all, I'm aware that there are many similar question like this, but the other solutions don't cover my specific case:

In my sqlite-database are existing binary data (SHA1 and similar hashes). With googling and reading the [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) i came up with the following:

```
import base64

class BlobField(models.Field):
""" 
Stores raw binary data
"""

description = 'Stores raw binary data'
__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    super(BlobField, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

def get_internal_type(self):
    return "BlobField"

def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection=None, prepared=False):
    return base64.decodestring(value)

def to_python(self, value):
    return base64.encodestring(value)
```

which does what I want, the value is encoded and decoded at the right moment, but on saving the model into the database it gives me the following error:

> DatabaseError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a
>   text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory =
>   str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your
>   application to Unicode strings.

How can I fix this? (Possibly without breaking all my unicode-compatibility in the rest of the app)

I cannot change the format of the db-columns since the data is used by another application.

---

EDIT:
As suggested by @filip-dupanovic, I adopted the BinaryField class as follows:

class BinaryField(models.Field):
    description = _("Raw binary data")

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['editable'] = False
    super(BinaryField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.max_length is not None:
        self.validators.append(validators.MaxLengthValidator(self.max_length))

def get_internal_type(self):
    return "BinaryField"

def get_default(self):
    if self.has_default() and not callable(self.default):
        return self.default
    default = super(BinaryField, self).get_default()
    if default == '':
        return b''
    return default

def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
    #value = super(BinaryField, self
    #    ).get_db_prep_value(value, prepared, connection=connection)
    #if value is not None:
    #    return connection.Database.Binary(value)
    return value
```

Notice the comments I had to insert at `get_db_prep_value()`, like this, it works as expected, if I uncomment the lines I get an error

> TypeError: get_db_prep_value() got multiple values for keyword argument 'connection'

I could live with this, but do not fully understand the implications of leaving it out. Will it still work even without the call to `super()`?

Comment: that's what I tried first, but it didn't work as well. I'm content with the current solution as shown in my edit, if no one posts any concerns about the comments I added I'll stick with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ticket [#2417](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2417), closed not long ago, added a `BinaryField` model field. You should look at [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/8ee1eddb7e148de89aebde9e68da495633fc1ec9), specifically the changes related to how you can map your internal `BlobField` field type to an appropriate type supported by your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
    value = super(BinaryField, self
        ).get_db_prep_value(value, connection, prepared)
    if value is not None:
        return connection.Database.Binary(value)
    return value
```

Comment: So what you did is changing the order of arguments in the call to `BinaryField.get_db_prep_value`, that took some careful reading.